# InertiaJS/Breeze throwing 'undefined reading $page' in prod

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

Upon running `yarn prod` inside a Laravel Breeze project with Vue3 and InertiaJS, this console error is thrown:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$page')`

I am unable to find anything anywhere else that will fix my issue, I first thought it was a `<script setup>` issue with Vue3, and tried the solution found in [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6282) which ended up not working for me, which makes me believe it's an Inertia issue potentially.

We have another project running Breeze, Vue3 and Inertia currently in production working perfectly fine which is only confusing myself even more.

**Dependencies as below**

`"laravel/framework": "^9.11",`

`"php": "^8.0.2",`

`"inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^0.5.4",`

`"vue-loader": "^17.0.0"`

`"vue": "^3.2.31",`

`"@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",`

`"@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You shared the error but not the culprit code.